# Why is Filezilla not accepting my PSFTP client?

Tags: sftp, putty, ftp

I have FileZilla 0.9.34beta configured to allow ONLY SFTP connections on port 8086 (not FTPS and not FTP either).   I am trying to connect to the server using Putty PSFTP.exe but it is failing to prompt me for any input.  It simply times out when trying to connect (after 1-2 minutes).  Here is the kind of thing I am seeing:

```
C:] psftp 127.0.0.1 -P 8086 -i myuser -v
Looking up host "127.0.0.1"
Connecting to 127.0.0.1 port 8086
Server unexpectedly closed network connection
Fatal: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

Filezilla log shows me this:

```
(000033) 6/29/2010 16:35:15 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000033) 6/29/2010 16:35:15 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.34 beta
(000033) 6/29/2010 16:35:15 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220 connected to 127.0.0.1
(000033) 6/29/2010 16:36:16 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 421 Login time exceeded. Closing control connection.
(000033) 6/29/2010 16:36:16 PM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> disconnected.
```

Filezilla client connects with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you enable sftp on filezilla server?  I don't see any evidence this is even possible in the interface or on their [wiki](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FileZilla_FTP_Server).  In fact the note `Support for SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is not implemented in Filezilla Server` seems to tell me that ssh is not supported and so you will never be able to connect with an sftp client.

Comment: Ahh.. your right. I'm using "EXPLICIT FTPS/TLS on port 8086". Hmm... maybe that has something to do with this problem. I guess PSFTP.exe doesn't support EXPLICIT FTPS? Thanks for the answer!  I dont know why I was thinking it was SFTP.